# Do Phar files in PHP equate to Assemblies in Dot Net?

Tags: php, phar

I am a Dot Net programmer that is now learning PHP just for fun and to see how PHP handles certain things. For me the basic concepts are easy because they are more or less common to web programming and programming in general like OOP, Sessions, Security etc. However there seem to be some areas which are confusing me as PHP is built differently from Dot Net world. One of those things is Phar files. In Dot Net we are so used to creating loosely coupled assemblies that we re-use everywhere. However in PHP most of the books that I have read and code I have seen will just create classes and use them directly in the project. The confusion that I have right now is:

- Are Phar files simmilar to dll files in Dot Net world?
- If so why they are not used often?
- Is their any performance hit when using Phar file?
- Can I use Phar files aggressively to create re-usable code libraries?

Kindly guide me if you have a lot of PHP experience, I want to know how the experts of PHP handle things.

Comment: I'd start by reading [this](http://php.net/manual/en/phar.using.intro.php). One of the first lines: "A Phar archive is used to distribute a complete PHP application or library in a single file."

Comment: You can compare the `phar` file a compact version of source code in one executable (php executable) file like an `exe` file in windows.

Comment: Not much people uses it, as it is not a compiled code just a compressed php files , and as PHP is more like web language there is an overhead of executing phar file ( needs to be uncompressed every time you use it ), hence will slow down web response etc.

Comment: @Wold yeah I read that help file and that actually caused the confusion. You see when we create an app we generate an exe for the client to install the app. Whereas we create assemblies to reuse them across multiple projects. My confusion was whether phar file is equivalent to exe or the dll?

Comment: @BojanT As mentioned in a comment on the accepted answer there is no overhead at all because PHP has an inbuilt op-code cache. The file is only uncompressed on the first compilation of the op-code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Are Phar files simmilar to dll files in Dot Net world?

No, they're not. They're just archives of plain-text source code

> If so why they are not used often?

Because they're extremely new

> Is their any performance hit when using Phar file?

No, they're just source code, gzipped. After extraction, they're just source code.

> Can I use Phar files aggressively to create re-usable code libraries?

What does "aggressively" mean? You cannot *aggressively* use tarballs. Use them or don't use them, they're just an archiving format for distributing code, whether library or application, in a single file. You limit your audience by using them, as they only work with relatively new versions of PHP.

Comment: Thanks meagar, you answer my question, just to clarify by extensive use I meant that getting in habit of creating small code libraries and then creating phar files of them and using them in my projects. I guess there is some confusion still on the performance issue as another comment suggest that there is an overhead of using them as they need to be uncompressed every time they are used.

Comment: @AfrazAli There should be no overhead at all as PHP's inbuilt op-code cache will deal with that.